# Optimizing Python for loop

Tags: python, optimization

I have a loop that is my biggest time suck for a particular function and I'd like to speed it up.  Current, this single loop takes up about 400ms, while the execution for the rest of the function takes about 610ms.

The code is:

```
for ctr in xrange(N):
    list1[ctr] = in1[ctr] - in1[0] - ctr * c1
    list2[ctr] = in2[ctr] - in2[0] - ctr * c2
    list3[ctr] = c3 - in1[ctr]
    list4[ctr] = c4 - in2[ctr]
```

N can be anywhere from around 40,000 to 120,000, and is the length of all lists (in1, in2, listN) shown.

Does anyone know some Python tricks to speed this up?  I already tried using map instead, as I know it tries to compile to more efficient code, but it was about 250ms slower.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that `list1`, `list2`, etc, all are numerical, consider using numpy arrays instead of lists.  For large sequences of integers or floats you'll see a huge speedup.

If you go that route, your loop above could be written like this:

```
ctr = np.arange(N)
list1 = n1 - n1[0] - ctr * c1
list2 = n2 - n2[0] - ctr * c2
list3 = c3 - ctr
list4 = c4 - ctr
```

And as a full stand-alone example for timing:

```
import numpy as np
N = 100000

# Generate some random data...
n1 = np.random.random(N)
n2 = np.random.random(N)
c1, c2, c3, c4 = np.random.random(4)

ctr = np.arange(N)
list1 = n1 - n1[0] - ctr * c1
list2 = n2 - n2[0] - ctr * c2
list3 = c3 - ctr
list4 = c4 - ctr
```

Of course, if your `list1`, `list2`, etc are non-numerical (i.e. lists of python objects other than floats or ints), then this won't help.

Comment: Instead of `ctr * c1` and `ctr * c2`, using `np.linspace` might be faster. Or it might not, something to be determined by profiling.

Comment: @Michael J. Barber - Internally `linspace` just does `np.arange(0, num) * step + start`, so I doubt that it would be faster than `ctr * c1`, etc. Of course, as you said, that's best determined by profiling, and I haven't checked it yet.  Regardless, there's still a lot of room for optimizations in the code snippet above.

Comment: This one sped up the total execution time from 600ms to 185ms.  This is plenty fast enough for me, as there's a few FFTs just past this that take 100ms, and I know I can't speed that up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There was a bit of a mistake originally (see below) These are more properly cached.

```
# These can be cached as they do not change.
base_in1 = in1[0]
base_in2 = in2[0]
for ctr in xrange(N):
    # these are being looked up several times. Look-ups take time in almost every
    # language. Look them up once and then use the new value.
    cin1 = in1[ctr]
    cin2 = in2[ctr]
    list1[ctr] = cin1 - base_in1 - ctr * c1
    list2[ctr] = cin2 - base_in2 - ctr * c2
    list3[ctr] = c3 - cin1
    list4[ctr] = c4 - cin2
```

### (Mistake below):

Originally I thought that this could be solved by caching constants:

```
# these values never change
ctr1 = ctr * c1
ctr2 = ctr * c2
in10 = ctr1 + in1[0]
in20 = ctr2 + in2[0]
for ctr in xrange(N):
    # these are being looked up several times. That costs time.
    # look them up once and then use the new value.
    cin1 = in1[ctr]
    cin2 = in2[ctr]
    list1[ctr] = cin1 - in10
    list2[ctr] = cin2 - in20
    list3[ctr] = c3 - cin1
    list4[ctr] = c4 - cin2
```

But as Tim pointed out, I had missed the `ctr` in my original attempt.

Comment: Actually lookups like these really only cost in some interpreted languages like python, no need to do so in eg Java. But great performance improvement in python indeed.

Comment: @Voo that depends. If you're talking about array look-ups, then I'll agree with you, but most of the time you're more likely to be dealing with List<T,T> and look-ups can be *incredibly* expensive if not done right.

Comment: Well most - if not all - compilers/JITs today do CSE and would therefore optimize the code in the same way as one would do manually anyhow. Now one exception to this would be volatile variables, but in that case the manual change already altered the semantics. Now I'm sure one can obfuscate code in such a way to confuse the compiler/JIT ;) but in general that should work.

Comment: @Voo The problem comes in when you're using List.get(2540) and your List is really a LinkedList. No compiler can fix that for you, it will just take time.

Comment: If the compiler can prove that the get has no side effects, it can and will. Now that's not necessarily trivial depending on language so you may be right (easy in c++ thanks to const I'd think and the JIT in java should do it as well)

Answer (score 1):

Optimization depends on the compiler but there are a couple of things you can try.  Glad to see you are profiling the code!

You can try:

1. Storing `in1[ctr]` and other multiply used expressions in a variable first (although most compilers can do this already, who knows).
2. Loop fission (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_fission) in case you are having cache problems, alternating between massive arrays.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've noticed, Python is bad at successive mathematical expressions and will slow down tremendously. Your best options are likely to use numpy as someone else said so the code runs in C. One more Python optimization to try is to use list comprehensions. List comprehensions are usually faster than map.

```
in = in1[0]
list1 = [x - in - i * c1 for i, x in enumerate(in1)]
```

This method doesn't involve using xrange at all (uses Python's very strong iteration functions).

Example using timeit.

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt="[x * 2 for x in xrange(1000)]", number=10000)
8.27007...
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt="map(lambda x: x * 2, xrange(1000))", number=10000)
19.5969...
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt="""lst=[0]*1000
for x in xrange(1000):
    lst[x] = x * 2
""", number=10000)
13.7785...
# this last one doesn't actually do what you want it to do, but for comparison
# it's faster because it doesn't have to store any data from the computation
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt="for x in xrange(1000): x * 2", number=10000)
6.98619...
```

(if you need help constructing the other 4 list comprehensions, just comment)

Edit: Some timeit examples.

Answer (score 0):

You could try re-writing it as several loops:

```
for ctr in xrange(N):
    list1[ctr] = in1[ctr] - in1[0] - ctr * c1

for ctr in xrange(N):
    list2[ctr] = in2[ctr] - in2[0] - ctr * c2

for ctr in xrange(N):
    list3[ctr] = c3 - in1[ctr]

for ctr in xrange(N):
    list4[ctr] = c4 - in2[ctr]
```

It may not be as stupid as it sounds. Measure it. One problem with this kind of code can be locality of reference. If you're jumping around memory you can work against cache. You may find zipping through arrays individually may be kinder on your cache.

You could also think of doing them in parallel threads.

Comment: Creating four ranges will cost more time than creating one, so this will be slower. Using four threads might help a bit. But I fear that the global interpreter lock will eat most of the performance.

Comment: Depends entirely on the data doesn't it?

Comment: Because of the GIL, there's no point in using threads (and there may not be a point in languages without the GIL. 400 ms may still be too short for the cost of creating threads, but you would have to profile to figure that out). As @Joe said, try it and see if it works (the cost of making the xrange is practically nothing).

Comment: Splitting them up into multiple loops slowed it down by about another 100ms.  I haven't tried threading it yet, though, and I'll let you know how it affects it.

Comment: Not really. All operations happen in memory, no threads does any blocking IO which means almost no parallel execution.

Answer (score 0):

[`itertools.count`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) is faster. [`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) generates a list in Python 2, you'll want [`itertools.imap`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) there.

Comment: `xrange()` is more efficient than `itertools.count()` :-/

Answer (score 0):

A map only helps if you have random access. In your case, a list is the correct data type.

Try to extract the <s>constants `in1[0] - ctr * c1` and `in2[0] - ctr * c2` out of the loop</s>. Opps. `ctr` is not a constant. You can try x1 = c1 and then x1 += c1 but I don't think the addition is much faster than multiply on todays CPUs.

Then, you should have a look at the [array module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) or [Numpy](https://numpy.org/). Instead of creating `list3` like in your code, create a copy of `in1`, invert all elements (`*-1`) and then add `c3` to each element. The mass mutation methods of array/Numpy will make this much faster.

Other than that, there is little you can do without touching the rest of the code. For example, instead of actually calculating `list3` and `list4`, you could create objects that return the values when they are necessary. But my guess is that you need all values, so this wouldn't help.

If that's not fast enough, you will have to use a different language or write a C module.

Answer (score 0):

Use [numpy](https://numpy.org/). The loop gets replaced by a few differences of arrays, the evaluation of which is done in C.

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat faster to use list comprehensions to calculate the contents of your lists than to use a for loop.

```
import random

N = 40000
c1 = 4
c2 = 9
c3 = 11
c4 = 8
in1 = [random.randint(1, 50000) for _ in xrange(N)]
in2 = [random.randint(1, 50000) for _ in xrange(N)]
list1 = [None for _ in xrange(N)]
list2 = [None for _ in xrange(N)]
list3 = [None for _ in xrange(N)]
list4 = [None for _ in xrange(N)]
in1_0 = in1[0]
in2_0 = in2[0]

def func():
    for ctr in xrange(N):
        list1[ctr] = in1[ctr] - in1_0 - ctr * c1
        list2[ctr] = in2[ctr] - in2_0 - ctr * c2
        list3[ctr] = c3 - in1[ctr]
        list4[ctr] = c4 - in2[ctr]

def func2():
    global list1, list2, list3, list4
    list1 = [(in1[ctr] - in1_0 - ctr * c1) for ctr in xrange(N)]
    list2 = [(in2[ctr] - in2_0 - ctr * c2) for ctr in xrange(N)]
    list3 = [(c3 - in1[ctr]) for ctr in xrange(N)]
    list4 = [(c4 - in2[ctr]) for ctr in xrange(N)]
```

And then timeit results:

```
% python -mtimeit -s 'import flup' 'flup.func()'
10 loops, best of 3: 42 msec per loop
% python -mtimeit -s 'import flup' 'flup.func2()'
10 loops, best of 3: 34.1 msec per loop
```